# how to read .properties file from particular location using java in linux os

Tags: java, linux, windows, properties-file

Hi all I am having 2 jar files(read.jar, write.jar) in the following folder structure:

```
app/read/read.jar
app/write/write.jar
```

The `write.jar` writes the values to the properties file present in `app/important.properties` and the `read.jar` reads from the `app/important.properties`. In the Java code I am calling the properties file using

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/app/important.properties");
```

This is working fine in Windows OS, but when I put this `app` in Linux OS in `/home/workspace/app` a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown. Then I changed the reading of file to:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./important.properties")
```

which also produced a `FileNotFoundException`. Can anyone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're using relative paths, as you first path is absolute path from the root/app directory

Comment: Are you reading and writing `important.properties` or `height.properties`??

Comment: sorry I am reading the important.properties how to give the path in linux? it always says file not found exception

Comment: Have you tried simply using `"important.properties"` or `"/home/workspace/app/important.properties"` ?

Comment: in windows it is working fine i gave like this `/app/important.properties` but in linux it is not working.

Comment: Linux interprets `"/to/my/file"` as the absolute path from the root directory like MadProgrammer stated. So if you want to use the absolute path, you need to specify the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

FileOutputStream will create the file if it does not exist but it **will not create any directory parts and fail with an FileNotFoundException** if the directory does not exist. You should check if the directory exist or not before writing.

Also check the write permissions on that directory in unix.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public static void loadProperFile(String fileName){
    try {
        String url=ReadProperties.class.getResource("/").toURI().getPath();
        String path=url+fileName;
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(path));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It works on mac and linux.I hope this will help you!

Comment: Or you could use the System property "user.dir" or File(".") which will return the current working directory (and IMHO would be easier to read :P)

Comment: it is creating the properties file in the `/app/write` folder. but I need the properties file to be created in `/app` folder.

Comment: If the properties files are in a .jar I'd recommend getResourceStream(), with the code above. Good job though.